# Subset variance order preserving function

Tags: order-theory, transformation, variance

Given a finite set with real numbers. X = {x1, x2, x3}. There can be a unique order defined for all the subsets using Variance operator.

e.g. X = {1, 2, 4}.

$$ {\displaystyle \operatorname {Var} (X)={\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-\mu )^{2},} $$ and $${\displaystyle \mu ={\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}x_{i}.}$$
Var({1, 4}) >  Var({1, 2, 4}) > Var({2, 4}) > Var({4}) = Var({2}) = Var({1}) = Var({}).

Is there any nontrivial function f(x) such that f(X) = {f(x1), f(x2), f(x3),...} preserve the same order?

f(x) = x and f(x) = -x would work.

Comment: There are no duplicates nor order in sets.  Define the variance operator of a set.

Comment: the variance operator of a set is just calculate variance of all the elements inside of the set , consider, the set is finite and elements is defined in R. $$ {\displaystyle \operatorname {Var} (X)={\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-\mu )^{2},} $$ and $${\displaystyle \mu ={\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}x_{i}.}$$

Answer (score 0):

The singleton and empty sets are not ordered by the variance.
The variance creates a preorder.

f(x) = ax, a /= 0 and f(x) = a + x
preserve the variance preorder.

Comment: yeah, any variance invariant transformation would do. what if f(x) itself is a discrete set mapping, is there anyway to prove the mapping is preserving order or not?